# Better way to check for Video.js object on instantiation?

Tags: javascript, video.js

I am really getting into object-oriented Javascript, and Video.js. In order to make the custom video controls appear each time the page is loaded, the cached Video.js object has to be disposed of, and rebuilt.

I have created the following script that correctly checks for a cached object, but wasn't sure if there was a better way, one that doesn't need to create a second global variable:

```
<div class="video-wrapper"></div>

<script>
    var VideoObj;

    var Continuum = function(container, el, shortName) {
        this.container = container;
        this.el = el;
        this.shortName = shortName;
    };

    Continuum.prototype = {
        /* Build up the <video> tag and and attributes */
        prepareVideo: function() {
            if(VideoObj) {
                VideoObj.dispose();
            }

            $(this.container).append($(this.el));

            $(this.shortName).attr({
                'id': 'video_1',
                'class': 'video-js vjs-default-skin',
                'controls': true,
                'poster': 'http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.jpg',
                'preload': false
            });

            this.createVideoObject('video_1');
        },

        /* Instantiate the object with the Video.js call */
        createVideoObject: function(vidID) {
            _V_(vidID, {}, function () {
                this.vidID = VideoObj = videojs(vidID);

                this.vidID.src([
                  { type: "video/mp4", src: "http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4" },
                  { type: "video/webm", src: "http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.webm" },
                  { type: "video/ogg", src: "http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.ogv" }
                ]);

                this.vidID.pause();
        });
    }
};

var vid = new Continuum('div.video-wrapper', '<video/>', 'video');
vid.prepareVideo();
```

Comment: If the page is completely reloading each time, there should be no reason why the player would already exist. Is there any details missing from this example, like this is happening inside an ajax driven javascript application where the entire page is not loaded on each new page, e.g. Angular or Ember?

Comment: heff, Yes the fragment above is being loaded via AJAX. I have broken out several HTML pieces into templates that get loaded into the index.html file. This is the only one with a video being rendered, which is why I've written it the way I did.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily check if videojs is loaded in this way:

```
videojs.getAllPlayers().length
```

If it is 0 you can rebuild it.

Other way is to iterate

```
videojs.getAllPlayers()
```

and dispose them before rebuilding.

Answer (score 0):

```
Boolean(videojs.players.myPlayerId);
```

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.